# <img>'s inside of ng-repeat-generated <md-card>'s don't show up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angular-material

I'm having a weird problem with `<img>`s in Angular Material's `<md-card>`:

- I am creating multiple `md-cards` using `ng-repeat`
- The data is coming from Google Firebase: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB7TA.png)
- Not all the cards show the image, only the second one does: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8T9k.png)
- See it live here: dev.oster-holzhaus.de/#/holzbau (I can't include more than two links at the moment)

My code:

```
<md-content class='md-padding' layout="row" layout-wrap layout-align="center">
<md-card style="width: 400px;" ng-repeat="service in services">
    <img ng-src={{service.imagepath}} class="md-card-image">
    <md-card-title>
        <md-card-title-text>
            <span class="md-headline">{{service.title}}</span>
            <span class="md-subhead">{{service.subhead}}.</span>
        </md-card-title-text>
    </md-card-title>
    <md-card-content>
        <p>{{service.text}}</p>
    </md-card-content>
    <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
        <md-button>Test</md-button>
    </md-card-actions>
</md-card>
</md-content>
```

- The critical step is in `line 3`.
- The data is pulled correctly, the only problem is that the image is only displayed on the second card.
- I tried switching to a local `imagePath`, but get the same weird thing

Has anyone made similar experiences or can even solve my problem? Thanks!

Regards
Enzo

Comment: Did you try adding " to `ng-src="{{service.imagepath}}"` ? Also close the image tag

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your image url which is coming through `service.imagepath` is coming on DOM in correct format or not.

You can check by writing `{{service.imagepath}}` any where inside the `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

If you want cards with images you should use `md-card-title-media` or place the image within `md-card-content` - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/zBQKmN?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content class='md-padding' layout="row" layout-wrap layout-align="center">
    <md-card style="width: 400px;" ng-repeat="service in services">      
        <md-card-title>
            <md-card-title-text>
                <span class="md-headline">{{service.title}}</span>
                <span class="md-subhead">{{service.subhead}}.</span>
            </md-card-title-text>
          <md-card-title-media>
            <img ng-src={{service.imagepath}} class="md-card-image" style="width:150px;">
          </md-card-title-media>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-card-content>
            <img ng-src={{service.imagepath}} class="md-card-image" style="width:150px;">
            <p>{{service.text}}</p>
        </md-card-content>
        <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
            <md-button>Test</md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.services = [
    {title: "Cow", subhead: "Animal", imagepath: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Cow_female_black_white.jpg"},
    {title: "Car", subhead: "Transport", imagepath: "http://i2.cdscdn.com/pdt2/2/6/2/1/700x700/nit0641243370262/rw/voiture-electrique-pour-enfant-2-x-30w-rouge.jpg"},
    {title: "House", subhead: "Building", imagepath: "http://www.smallworks.ca/wp-content/uploads/exterior11.jpg"}
  ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
My markup did work, but I had a spelling error in "imagePath"/"imagepath", and in the code it also was `{{service.imagepath}}` (with a lowercase p). So only the second service with "imagepath" could be loaded.

Thank you for your efforts Guys!

Regards
Enzo